# How to add a group into a node tree with Python

Tags: python, scripting, materials

How do I add an already created node group into a node tree?

I have found that this works:

```
group = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
group.node_tree = other_group.node_tree
```

But it creates a copy of `other_group` instead of just referencing it. So how would I go about just straight adding it to the node tree?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After adding the new node group node you can assign the `node_group` data type to the `node_tree`:

```
group = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
group.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups['OldNodeGroupName']
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know is with operator with overwritten context. That means you will have to have a Node Editor window somewhere open:

```
context_copy = bpy.context.copy()
context_copy['area'] = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type=='NODE_EDITOR')
bpy.ops.node.add_node(context_copy,
                      type="ShaderNodeGroup",
                      settings=[{"name":"node_tree", "value":"bpy.data.node_groups['GROUP']"}])
```

Comment: I can't believe there wouldn't be a way to do this otherwise, if no one else answers with something different then I will accept this. Thanks